# Can you relate volume elements under nonlinear, many-to-many transformations?

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant

I've parameterized to reduce the dimensionality of my problem from $\textbf{R}^3 \rightarrow \textbf{R}^2$:

$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\rightarrow (y_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),y_2(x_1,x_2,x_3))$

I was hoping to glean some information on how the volume elements transform, similar to the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622725/determinant-of-non-square-jacobian). In short, it seems like I could relate the volume elements through:

$dy_1dy_2 = |\sqrt{\textbf{J}^T\textbf{J}}|dx_1dx_2dx_3$

if the map is linear.

Mine, however, is nonlinear/many-to-many and everything I've been able to find says that this relationship only works for linear maps.

Is there any meaningful relationship between these two volume elements?